# What is meant by visualizing an embedding space(neural network)?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I was reading about an activity recognition paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.07750.pdf. Here, they use 3D convolution on inception v1 to perform activity recognition. I was listening to a talk that said visualizing embedding space of the features from the video.

1) What does it mean to visualize an embedding space? Are you looking at the filters that it has learnt or are you looking for clusterings of similar activities?

2) Do you just visualize the weight matrix for seeing the features that it is capturing? If yes, which weight matrix?

3)Does tf.summary.image() help in visualizing the weight matrix?

Answer (score 1):

The embedding space is the space of the features produced by some learning algorithm. In the specific case of a (convolutional) neural network, this usually means one of the output feature maps (flattened) at some predefined layer or the output of one of the fully connected layers.

What one would visualize is **not** the weight matrix, but the values of the produced features for some input test data. For example one takes the full test set and passes it through the network and computes the features for each image at a specific layer, and then visualizes those values.

TensorBoard has functionality to automatically visualize embeddings and other feature spaces, you should take a [look](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/embedding) at it.

Note that in some application contexts like NLP an embedding has a slightly different definition but the use is the same.